# SQL select and update

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to make an SQL query that returns a set of rows and also sets a certain column in those rows to null. So if I had a table like

```
column1 column2 column3
a       b       c
a       b       d
e       f       g
```

I would want to do the pseudo-SQL `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = a AND ALSO SET column2 = null` and have that return my first two rows as they are above, while leaving the table looking like

```
column1 column2 column3
a       null    c
a       null    d
e       f       g
```

Can I do this?

Comment: you can. in two queries.

Comment: you cannot do select and update in a single query

Comment: Yeah even a child could do that but I want one query. I think it'd be faster because it's already operating on those rows to do the select so it doesn't have to find them again for an update.

Comment: @InquisitiveIdiot mysql make their source code available, go nuts adding the functionality.

Comment: @InquisitiveIdiot sorry to tell you, but what you want is not much relevant in this case, it is just not how it works. But about the speed - if select is fast enough, then the update has things already cached so it can find the same rows even faster. Or you can use temporary table to find those rows and store identifier - and then join to it in both queries to have the rows "at hand"

Answer (score 0):

First you **cannot** use the `select` and `update` together in one single query.

Second if you just want to display `null` where `column1 = 'a'` then you can try this:

```
SELECT column1,CASE WHEN column1='a' THEN NULL ELSE column2 END as column2
      ,column3
FROM yourtable
```

**EDIT:**

However if you want to get the original data and then update the values then you have to write two seperate queries. One in which you select the resords and the second in which you update the records of the column2 of your table.

Comment: If you read the question, he wants the original data returned, and THEN the field updated.

Comment: @pala_:- I am not sure where is that written as I focussed on this line: `So I want to make an SQL query that returns a set of rows and also sets a certain column in those rows to null.`

Comment: second lot of text, under the table definition.

Comment: @pala_:- May be I am missing something  but I am not able to find that where is the point of "original data return" written?

Comment: `have that return my first two rows as they are above,` ie, in the original table

Comment: @pala_:- Ooh man, its not like that, I am afraid that this cannot be the point as then it would be a simple update query which I dont think is the point here.

Comment: it sort of is the point. he wants to select the data, then update the data. only he wants to do it in one query.

Comment: @pala_:- Yes so for that I have already added that `First you cannot use the select and update together in one single query.`

Comment: yeah. i see it - was it there originally? maybe i'm just criminally blind today

Comment: @pala_:- Yes I added that initially. :) No issues if you didnt see that ;) No ninja edits in between :))

Comment: if you edit your post a little bit i'll remove the overly hasty downvote :)

Comment: @pala_:- Done that. And added the point of confusion as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @column1 varchar(2);
SET @column1 = (SELECT distinct column1 FROM table WHERE column1 = 'a' );

select * from table where column1 = @column1;
update table set column2 = null where column1 = @column1;
```

this work for me in sql server..which will return the row as it is earlier and will update the column with new values in background

Comment: mysql has no `top` capability.

Comment: can use `distinct` then