# sql -- select and update

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've being trying to amend the solution found in this tutorial to write an SQL query that both SELECTs and UPDATEs my table:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497491/sql-select-and-update)

```
DECLARE @column1 varchar(2);
SET @column1 = (SELECT `Id`, `Url` FROM `MyTable` WHERE `Retrieved` = 0);

SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `AdId`, `Url` = @column1;
UPDATE `MyTable` SET `Retrieved` = 1 where `Id`, `Url` = @column1;
```

What i'm trying to achieve the following simultaneously:

```
SELECT Id, Url FROM MyTable WHERE Retrieved = 0
UPDATE MyTable SET Retrieved = 1
```

***for the rows where i have SELECTed the results from***

Basically, i want to select all data from ID and Url columns where the Retrieved column equals 0. I then want to set the Retrieved column to 1 for the rows i have selected.

Comment: Is the SELECT _just_ to filter the records that are updated or do you want to return them to the client as well?

Comment: This kind of functionality ("*simultaneously*" returning a resultset and updating rows) is not a native SQL function. Emulating this is going to require more than one SQL statement. You could emulate this with a stored procedure. A call to the stored procedure could return the resultset and apply the updates. But the implementation is going to be DBMS dependent. How you go about actually doing it is going to depend on which DBMS you are using... MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, et al.  I think a bigger question is *why* are you trying to do this? What's the *actual problem* you need to solve?

Comment: The syntax so strongly suggests MySQL that I added the tag.  @Baz, please tag your questions with the database you are actually using.  If I am wrong, please fix the tag(s).

Comment: @spencer7593 - Ok, i've taken onboard what you've said and added a Boolean column to MyTable. I've then written a second query which updates the Boolean column once the first query has been completed. I dont know why i didnt think of this before...! To answer the second part of the question (eg Why): MyTable is constantly being filled with new data. I therefore need to be sure to only pull new records from it every time i run the query in questions.

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" SQL method would be:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET Retrieved = 1
    WHERE id IN (SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Retrieved = 0);
```

That does not work in MySQL.  Assuming that `id` is unique in `MyTable` (a reasonable assumption in my opinion), then this does what you want:

```
UPDATE MyTable
    SET Retrieved = 1
    WHERE Retrieved = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t SET t.Retrieved=1 FROM MyTable t WHERE t.Retrieved=0
```

This is only updating rows, that essentially you've selected.  In your case you want to update rows where the selected rows Retrieved column is equal to 0.

The other thing and maybe for readibility or you need the rows returned you can use a cte.

```
--first get only the records you need
WITH MyRecords_cte
AS
 ( 
  SELECT Id, URL, Retreived FROM MyTable WHERE Retreived=0
 )


UPDATE MyRecords_cte SET MyRecords_cte.Retreived=1
```

Once you're done with the update you can return the data.